# Error in creating database in MongoDB using composer

Tags: php, database, mongodb

I'm trying to create a database using composer. I've **demo.php** as the main file and running the code on localhost.

Error message :

> Fatal error: Uncaught
>   MongoDB\Driver\Exception\ConnectionTimeoutException: No suitable
>   servers found (`serverSelectionTryOnce` set): [socket timeout calling
>   ismaster on '127.0.0.1:27017'] in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\phpmongodb\vendor\mongodb\mongodb\src\Database.php:201
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\phpmongodb\vendor\mongodb\mongodb\src\Database.php(201):
>   MongoDB\Driver\Manager->selectServer(Object(MongoDB\Driver\ReadPreference))
>   1 C:\xampp\htdocs\phpmongodb\demo.php(8): MongoDB\Database->createCollection('emplcollection') 2 {main} thrown
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpmongodb\vendor\mongodb\mongodb\src\Database.php
>   on line 201

What could be the reason for this?

My code:

```
<?php
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    $client = new MongoDB\Client;
    $companydb = $client->companydb;
    $result1 = $companydb->createCollection('emplcollection');
    var_dump(result1);
?>
```

Comment: [Did you install the MongoDB server?](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/installation/) The "Driver" ( thing you installed with composer ) is not the actual database. It's just a means of communicating with that other thing that is either 1. Not installed. 2. Not running. Odds are on number 1.

Comment: Yes, I've installed the mongodb-php driver.

Comment: That's not what you were asked. Click on the link and tell us if you actually ever did what is described there. The **database server is NOT the driver**.